# How to fix timeout when authenticating with Twitch?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, twitch

When trying to authenticate with Twitch, using Django-allauth, my request times out.

I'm currently testing it locally and I don't have any of my ports open.
I have the callback url set to the following "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/twitch/login/callback/" on both the twitch app and in the allauth site.

I end up at the following URL: "http://id.twitch.tv/accounts/twitch/login/callback/?code=[SOMECODE]&scope=user_read&state=[SOMESTATE]"

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Turns out all I had to do what change 127.0.0.1 to localhost and everything works perfectly now.

Comment: you ran into a timeout because of the wrong url. If the user authorizes your application, the user is redirected to your redirect URI, with an authorization code: `https://<your registered redirect URI>/?code=<authorization code>` in your case the browser will redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/twitch/login/callback/?code=xxxx not to twitch.tv

Comment: Turns out just changing it to localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 fixed my issue...
Thanks for your response thought, for whatever reason this made me try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1